# Measuring the Momentum of a Quantum System using Position Measurements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-measurements

A basic way to measure the momentum of a charged particle is to know that (classically) it follows a circular trajectory in a uniform magnetic field perpendicular to the plane of its trajectory, with a radius $R$ given by $$R=\frac{p}{eB}$$ in the nonrelativistic regimes, where p is the momentum of the particle, e its charge, and B the magnetic field strength.

Reading in my quantum mechanics textbooks, the basic idea thus to measure momentum is by sending a stream of particles through a slit as shown in the figure below, which guarantees (classically) that the momentum is essentially in the $+\hat{z}$ direction. Beyond is a region of uniform magnetic field, followed by a set of detectors. If the intensity of the source is very weak, flashes will appear on the detectors one by one; and using the expression for $R$ we can associate with each flash a value of momentum in the $+\hat{z}$ direction depending on the position of the flash, $p = ReB$.

[image: diagram of experiment]

My confusion however comes in that in order to measure the momentum, we have measured the position of the particle as well! If we can see the point at which the detector flashed, we have certainly determined the position. Thus again, we know the position, and we also know the momentum. This seems to violate Heisenberg's Uncertainty principle! What am I missing here?

Comment: This seems one of the more clever ways to flout HUP. The exact way it fails is hard to pinpoint since in the quantum reality it doesn't have a well defined trajectory so the initial assumption is wrong.

Comment: What you have there is a completely classical system. There is absolutely no need to drag quantum mechanics into it. Neither will such a setup come anywhere close to showing you quantum mechanical limits. If you want to test the HUP with anything resembling "precision", then you have to prepare Gaussian states to start with.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to measure the momentum of single quanta](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.12303.pdf) by J. K. Freericks (2023), arxiv version.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the equation you wrote cannot be correct at a fundamental level. In fact the equation is not compatible with the canonical commutation relation

$$
\big [ x_\alpha , p_\beta \big ] = i \hbar \delta_{\alpha,\beta} \, . \ \ \ \ (1)  
$$

In other words $\mathbf{p}$ cannot be a function of $\mathbf{x}$ otherwise the variables would commute.

Not surprisingly Eq. (1) is at the basis of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle.

Comment: OP's method is one used even at ATLAS at the LHC - so the claim that it is wrong is also a claim that the momentum measurements there, and then also the corresponding cross sections, are wrong. Are you sure this is the issue?

Comment: For example this presentation they have on page 18: https://www.desy.de/~garutti/LECTURES/ParticleDetectorSS12/L9_Tracking.pdf

Comment: Not only them but overall this is a common method of getting the momentum. For example in bubble chambers, cloud chambers, wire chambers too, the momentum is inferred by the curvature.

Comment: @doublefelix this is a very interesting point. I agree with you at a superficial level, but I also agree with canonical commutation relations. Strictly speaking the radius is not exactly the position. One could still have indeterminacy along the arc, however I'm not sure if this would be compatible with CCR.

Comment: Well, in the LHC it is not the radius which is directly measured. The pixel detectors measure the individual positions of the particle along the trajectory. From there those positions are fit to a circle from which the radius is inferred (there are some additional considerations but that is the principle). However there is nonetheless an uncertainty in the position $\Delta x$ and an uncertainty in the momentum $\Delta p$ in the measurement and I see no reason to believe that their product should violate HUP. So that seems to me to be the answer here, simply that we have measured x and p but

Comment: not broken any bounds through doing so.

Comment: If $x$ and $p$ where functionally related (in a smooth way), the uncertainty in position would be proportional to the uncertainty in the momentum. And by making precise measurements of position one could violate the HUP. What I'm trying to say is that the equation $R=p/(eB)$ is a classical equation and cannot be true at a fundamental, quantum, level. You can use it to obtain position and momentum but then you will see that, surprisingly, the error in position and momentum satisfy HUP. This is, in principle, in contrast with the equation itself.

Comment: (as I said, according to that equation there should be no lower bound on the product of the errors).

Comment: The precise argument must take into account that position and momentum are not scalars but three dimensional vectors, but the main idea still holds. It is true though that one could measure very precisely the position along a vertical axis and the momentum along a horizontal (perpendicular) axis.

Comment: The point about proportional errors is good, but in the case of the LHC measurement, that is not true, because in order to get accurate position information one has to disturb the wavefunction more and more. More than 1 position measurement is needed to infer the radius, and if you make a very accurate measurement you won't be able to measure "where the particle would have been, had you not made a measurement". If you disturb very little then this is not a large source of error.

Comment: As for the experiment by OP I have to think for a sec..

Comment: If the particle hits the wall at a 90 degree angle (it looks roughly this way in the diagram) then the HUP doesn't apply since the position information is on the plane of the detector and the momentum information is perpendicular to it. But it looks like there would usually be some component of momentum not perpendicular. To reduce the uncertainty in $p$ you would need to know the starting position of the beam very well, and make it a very thin beam. This would make the momentum uncertain in the directions perpendicular to the beam, but the slit keeps the momentum bounded.

Comment: Still the slit can only get so thin before you start to have interaction between it and the particle. It seems like here, you could start to see an increase in certainty in momentum cause a disruption in the particle's state after measurement, and you can no longer suppose that the trajectory will be circular because it has been disturbed. I think to do the math here would be complicated, but it seems in principle like HUP could possibly hold. Then again I do not have a proof, this is just a conceptual sketch, which is not worth as much.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first time I face this intriguing problem. Here is my opinion. Let $y$ be the direction of the incoming beem of electrons (or any other type of electrically charged quantum particle) in the region where the magnetic field $B$ along $z$ takes place.

In my view, the experiment is a **measurement of the longitudinal momentum component $p_y$** of an **incoming particle**, thus **before the electron enters the magnetic room**.
But this value is obtained by observing the **final transverse position on the screen**.

If $\psi$ is the incoming wavefunction, we can decompose its fourier transform $\hat{\psi}$ into a sum of $N$ packets awith  $p_y$ approximately defined $\hat{\psi}_j$, with respective  momenta $p_{yj}$. These packets superpose in space and have a common  extension $\Delta p_y$ in momentum space along the longitudinal direction and a common **transverse extension** $\Delta x$ in space. This transverse extension is of the same magnitude of the slit.

The center of  every packet, when entering the region of magnetic field, **evolves according to the Ehrenfest theorem** along a classical curved trajectory.

Each packet also experiences  some deformation of its shape, the transverse width in particular. We can disregard  that deformation if the trip is sufficiently fast. Or we can take it into account by a finer analysis. The sensitivity of rhe screen mus be able to distinguish these packets.

At the end of the trip, we see **only one spot** on the screen and this chooses **which** wavepacket reaced the screen with its own longitudinal momentum $p_{yj}$. That is a measurement of the incoming longitudinal momentum.

Superficially at least, I do not think that there is any contradiction with the Heisenberg principle, since the position the screen is transverse with respect to the component of momentum. Also the momentum is the incoming one and the position is the final one.

Answer (score 0):

> Thus again, we know the position, and we also know the momentum. This seems to violate Heisenberg's Uncertainty principle! What am I missing here?

Your argument misses that all measurement values have uncertainties. Actual measurement will determine both position and momentum magnitude at the moment of impact with some uncertainties, and these cannot be both made arbitrarily small.

The formula

$$
p = ReB
$$

assumes that the particle exits the slit radially into the cylinder. This is not exactly true, because wide slit allows for different angles of momentum already outside the cylinder, and narrow slit, although it limits direction of momentum outside, causes diffraction, where momentum when particle is different from the momentum when outside. The formula above does not take into account different possible directions of momentum inside the cylinder right after the particle passes the slit, so it is not accurate enough to challenge the uncertainty relations.